# Локализация анкеты кандидата

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Может нам локализовать анкету кандидата при подаче заявке на выборы?

На странице заполнения анкеты имеются следующие нелокализованные сообщения

- Nominating {имя_кандидата}
- Candidate statement (required)
- Explain why you would make a good moderator.
- Questionnaire (optional)
- Answering these questions will give voters more information about how you think this site should be moderated. All of the questions are in quote format with a break in between. Enter your answers to each question between each block quote.
- [Answer {number} here]
- Withdraw

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Переводы добавлены.

Должны появиться в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.4.4.43375

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Еще мелочь https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuwJu.png (скрин кривоват, SO не виноват) - под заявкой кандидата в модераторы есть нелокализованная кнопка `Withdraw`, должно быть "Отозвать" или что-то такое, я полагаю.

Comment: C `[Answer N here]` что-то не ладно. Если сегодня не подхватится, надо на MSE писать.

Comment: да, есть такое...она с фронта может прилетает?

Comment: @МихаилРебров посмотрим позже. Тут еще весь редактор не имеет переводов. Не понятно, зачем они сюда его впихнули. Видимо, потестировать так решили слегка.

Comment: сам шаблон анкеты как мне кажется готовится Community Manager'ом и хранится где-то в базе, а не в шаблонах. И оттуда же прилетает `[Answer N here]`, который был банально вставлен Катей вручную

Comment: @МихаилРебров не думаю, что тут что-то вручную вставлялось. Особенно учитывая наличие строк в traducir.

Comment: @МихаилРебров завел [багу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388117/339911)